# Anaconda navigator is not responding

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, python-module, anaconda3

Suddenly the navigator stop working, I reinstalled it several times but each time when I double click it, it again goes to the installing process. I have even tried the older versions of python as well as the python 3.8 to build a supportive environment for navigator but it doesn't help. Anaconda prompt also not responding to any command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details such as your OS (Linux, Mac or Windows) and your Anaconda Navigator version.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and the navigator version is Anaconda3, the python I have installed is python3.7.7 because Anaconda navigator site shows that it is compatible with python 3.7 version

Comment: I'll suggest installing an older version, which can be found here: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

Comment: but the older versions have some issues with modules like one-hot encoder, it won't support the modules